# Passing the value of vector string to the win32 Function SetWindowText in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

How could i pass the value of vector string to the win32 Function SetWindowText in C++.

so far this is my code for that:

```
vector <string> filelist;
string path;
path = Text;
filelist = GetPath(path);
SetWindowText(EditShow,filelist);
```

Comment: What kind of window is this?  If it's a list or combo box, you'll probably want to send messages one at a time to fill the entries in appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could concatenate them all into one string and pass that as a c-string:

```
#include <sstream>   // for std::stringstream
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy
#include <iterator>  // for std::ostream_iterator

std::stringstream buffer;
std::copy(filelist.begin(), filelist.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(buffer, "\n");
SetWindowText(EditShow,buffer.str().c_str());
```

Comment: what is the header file for this one??

Comment: 'ostream_iterator' : undeclared identifier,  'std::string' : illegal use of this type as an expression, identifier "ostream_iterator" is undefined here are the errors

Comment: @Andro: I added the required headers to my answer. You can also just google for these names of course.

Comment: it doesn't give the proper output. it doesn't next line the output;

Comment: @Andro: I do not understand. Please edit your question and show an example of the output you get and the output you would expect.

Comment: okay, i forgot to say that Editshow is a Multiline TextBox. The Output only goes one line. It supposed to have an output with data seperated by next line

Comment: @Andro: I am sorry, I cannot help you with that, as I do not know much about the Win32 API. Maybe if you post the code how you create and fill the test-box in your question, others might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you seem to be trying to insert a list of strings into SetWindowText.

since each window can only have one title, SetWindowText cannot process a list. Instead, you should retrieve a single string from the list, and use it as a parameter to SetWindowText

`string windowText = filelist[0];`

The documentation from [SetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reveals that the function expects a `LPCTSTR lpString`.

Since all we have right now is a `string`, we have to use

`LPCTSTR title = windowText.c_str();`

It is possible that this line will not compile with the following error message :
cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR'
You will have to change the default character set in your project. [Here is how you do it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/c1b08c0a-a803-41c3-ac8c-84eba3be1ddb)

Finally you can call

`SetWindowText(EditShow,title);`

Comment: Or, instead of changing the project, you can use a std::wstring in place of std::string.   :-)